# How to call a method multiple times to change a variable?

Tags: java, methods, repeat

I am trying to call an `accelerate` method on a `speed` variable that adds 5 to the `speed` variable each time it is called. I'm able to do it once in the constructor:

```
public int getAccelerate() {
    accelerate = (speed + 5);
    return accelerate;
}
```

and display it using

```
System.out.println(car1.getAccelerate());
```

but that only works once, which displays 105 if the speed variable is 100.

My question is: how do I update the speed variable each time the `accelerate` method is called to reflect the new speed value?

Calling it 5 times gives me the output

> 105
>   105
>   105
>   105
>   105

where I am trying to get the output

> 105
>   110
>   115
>   120
>   125

by calling the *same* method 5 times.

Comment: What are  `speed` and `accelerate`? note that you are only reassigning a new value  to `accelerate` while `speed` is not getting changed (hence you always get the same return value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what is happening. Your method takes `speed`, adds `5` to it, and puts that value in the variable `accelerate`. Then it returns `accelerate`. So every time, you change `accelerate` based on `speed`, but you never change `speed`! So for example, if `speed` is `100`, the first call will return `100 + 5`, the second call will return `100 + 5`, and so on.

If you want this to work properly, change accelerate each time:

```
public int getAccelerate()
{
    accelerate = (accelerate + 5);
    return accelerate;
}
```

Or you could change speed each time:

```
public int getAccelerate()
{
    speed = (speed + 5);
    return speed;
}
```

Comment: Please use `x += 5` instead of `x = (x + 5)`.

Comment: @ShaunTighe no problem, happy to help! please remember to upvote and accept.